# how do I join multiple list with varargs in java?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to join  several list using `Stream API`.

I found a useful example at stackoverflow:

```
List<Integer>list1=Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Integer>list2=Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
List<Integer>list3=Arrays.asList(7,8,9);
List<Integer>list4=Arrays.asList(10,0,-1);

List<Integer> newList = 
    Stream.of(list1, list2, list3,list4)
          .flatMap(Collection::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());       
System.out.println(newList); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, -1]
```

Nice. But in my case, I can`t determine how many lists to use this Stream.of().

I thought about using varargs at jdk8. like this

```
public List<Integer> getNewList(List... list) {
    List<Integer> newList = 
         Stream.of(list)
               .flatMap(Collection::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return newList;
}

getNewList(list1, list2, list3, list...)
```

Unfortunately, it didn`t work well. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the type of `List` parameters you are passing as var args, and you can also use `Arrays.stream` instead of `Stream.of`

```
 public static List<Integer> getNewList(List<Integer>... list){
    return Arrays.stream(list)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.stream` should do the trick:

```
public static <T> List<T> merge(List<T>... lists) {
    return Arrays.stream(lists)
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

---

BTW, I've just noticed that your solution is almost fine. The only thing you need to add is `<Integer>`. So `Stream.of` should be also fine.

```
public List<Integer> getNewList(List<Integer>... list) {
    List<Integer> newList = 
         Stream.of(list)
               .flatMap(Collection::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return newList;
}
```

In fact, `Stream::of` calls `Arrays::stream` under the hood. So you can use any of them for your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. Use `Arrays.stream()` to stream the array of lists via the varargs syntax.

```
public static <T> List<T> getNewList(List<T>... list) {
    return  Arrays.stream(list).flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: WJS, If answering first is the top 'virtue' for you, then you should consider deleting your post. Since you've posted it 1 minute after @Deadpool. Be consistent and stick to your own standards. :-)

Comment: That's arguable difference. A perfect candidate for a comment, btw. My solution combines both others, although I came up with mine before seeing them. I was just running my code in IDE in order to make sure it actually works.